# Object loses a reference to another when saving database changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So this will be slightly unorthodox question in the sense that I've not done my proper research, but that is mainly because this bug has left me so baffled that I have no clue on how to verbalize it in a way that actually gets search hits on Google. So, to put it simply:

Problem background:
I have a many-to-many relation in a Code-First ASP.NET MVC/Web project. One model is user while another is project. As per making a many-to-many relation in Code-First, project has an ICollection (which is instantiated as a list) called users and user has an ICollection (also a list) called projects. In addition, project has a user element called owner, and only the user who is referenced in that element has the rights to add other users to the project. To owner, the owned project is just another member in the collection.

Problem:
In the controller that adds the user to the project and project to the user, following lines are called:

```
        project.users.Add(user);
        db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
        user.Projects.Add(project);
        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

        Owner.Projects.Add(project); // My current bubblegum solution to the problem

        db.SaveChanges();
        // Here is where the problem happens
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
```

Basically, when the context saves the changes in the database, the reference the owner has to the project in its projects list "disappears". As in, when going step by step through the function, the owner still has the reference before calling db.SaveChanges(), but it's not there anymore when the code gets to the return statement.

While my current "bubblegum" solution works, I don't trust it enough to leave it at that. I want to know how this happens, *why* this happens, and most importantly, how to fix it. So, if anyone knows, or anyone comes up with ideas how to verbalize it to Google efficiently, please, fire away.

**EDIT:**
Started to wonder and checked: Lets say user1 has been added to the project, and owner adds user2 to it. It seems that in this case, user1 also loses the reference to the project, meaning that my "bubblegum" doesn't even work. Project keeps the references to the users, but users lose the references to the projects.

**EDIT 2:**
As per request, the collection entries in the models. First, the entry in the user model:

```
public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

And the entry in project model:

```
public virtual ICollection<BuildieUser> users { get; set; }
```

BuildieUser is the name of the model that extends the IdentityUser model, and the model that I use. Hope this brings some more light to the situation.

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Xevas

Comment: Show the relevant entities

Comment: I bet the poco is missing the `virtual` keyword on the association property!

Answer (score 0):

I must thank haim770 and his/her comment, even though I first misread it (which is why my second edit is what it is). After rereading it and thinking about it for a moment, it made me think about the file where I make my context, and more importantly, the modelBuilder.

It seems that I forgot to add the following snippet to the OnModelBuilding method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BuildieUser>().HasMany(p => p.Projects).WithMany(u => u.users)
            .Map(u => u.MapRightKey("Project_Id").MapLeftKey("User_Id")
            .ToTable("BuildieUserProject"));
```

After adding this, the code seems to be working without a hitch. So, thank you, haim.